# Makefile: What does 'make $* clean' mean?

Tags: makefile

I know  what `make clean` does.

But what does `make $* clean` do?

I'm not able to find a clear explanation anywhere.

Comment: It depends on the context. Where do you see it?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't disclose more information. Thanks for the Answer

Answer (score 11):

As Ross says, we can't help because you haven't provided enough context. You need to provide at least the rule in which the `make $* clean` appears.

However, I'll guess it looks something like this:

```
%.xyz:
        make $* clean
```

Here, `$*` is an [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) which will expand to the stem of the target (the text matching the `%` in the pattern).  So, if you invoke `make foobar.xyz`, this rule would invoke `make foobar clean`: it would run a sub-make, build the `foobar` target, then build the `clean` target.

I've not seen anything quite like the above, although I can think of reasons for doing it.  Far more common would be if you mistyped the command and it really said `make -C $* clean`, giving a rule like this:

```
%.xyz:
        make -C $* clean
```

(note you should *never* use the static string `make` when invoking a sub-make; you should *always* use `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}`).  In this example running `make foobar.xyz` would run `make -C foobar clean`, which means change to the directory `foobar` and run the `clean` target there.

Comment: MadScientist. Your answer helped! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If it is invoked from a shell script, then `$*` is expanded to the arguments passed to the shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# filename clean.sh
make $* clean
```

The above shell script can be invoked like,

```
#./clean.sh --silent
```

Which will eventually pass the `--silent` to the `make` application and execute the following command.

```
#make --silent clean
```

Finally, `$*` in a shell-script is expanded by the shell, not by the `make` application.